# Common methods and different constructors

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I am working in custom MVC php web application.
Here is what I have at this moment:

- A class "CtrlBase" which all controllers should extend.
- And because the application have 3 different parts (applications (I will use the word applications here)) that are independent from the user's point of view, but a lot of functionality is shared between the 3 apps I have a specific controller for each app that extends "CtrlBase":  CtrlBaseAdmin, CtrlBaseCms, CtrlBaseWeb.

  - The main difference between the 3 different controllers that should be taken into account at this level is in the constructor.
  - I have a CRUD controller for users that has the same functionality in all 3 apps except that each extends the specific base controller depending on the app.

All the methods: index, edit, add, and delete are the same for all three apps but the parent constructor is different and all the controllers of the same app extend the same parent controller.

So my question is how to avoid this code duplication (index, edit, add and delete functions are the same for all Users controllers in the three apps)?

Because the description is not very clear I am adding a code demo that you can use to understand it better.

First we have a Base controller that has all the common functionality:

```
/**
 * Controller Base
 */
class CtrlBase {

   /**
    * Class constructor
    */
   protected function __construct() {
      echo __METHOD__ . PHP_EOL;
   }

}
```

Then we have three base controllers that extend this base controller and add som stuff that is specific to each app. Obviously this is the base controller that is extended by all the controllers in the current app. So we have 3 app specific base controllers:

**CtrlBaseAdmin.php**

```
require_once('CtrlBase.php');

class CtrlBaseAdmin extends CtrlBase {

   function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      echo __METHOD__ . ": " . "processing some stuff specific to admin." . PHP_EOL;
   }

}
```

**CtrlBaseCms.php**

```
require_once('CtrlBase.php');

class CtrlBaseCms extends CtrlBase {

   function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      echo __METHOD__ . ": " . "processing some stuff specific to cms." . PHP_EOL;
   }

}
```

**CtrlBaseWeb.php**

```
require_once('CtrlBase.php');

class CtrlBaseWeb extends CtrlBase {

   function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      echo __METHOD__ . ": " . "processing some stuff specific to web." . PHP_EOL;
   }

}
```

This works very well. because all I did so far is to make the common functionality of the base controllers in a parent class and I kept what is specific to the given app in its specific base controller. When I have a controller that is specific to the app and not used elsewhere everything is fine:

**CtrlNotCommon.php**

```
require_once('CtrlBaseWeb.php');

class CtrlNotCommon extends CtrlBaseWeb {

   function __construct() {
      echo __METHOD__ . ": " . "This controller functionality is specific to web only and not used elsewhere. So no problem here." . PHP_EOL;
      parent::__construct();

   }

}
```

But now look at this three controllers that have common functionality in the three apps:

**CtrlCommonFeatureAdmin.php**

```
require_once('CtrlBaseAdmin.php');

class CtrlCommonFeatureAdmin extends CtrlBaseAdmin {

   function __construct() {
      echo __METHOD__ . ": " . "This controller functionality is (methods index and add) common to web, admin and cms." . PHP_EOL;
      parent::__construct();  
   }

   function index() {
      echo __METHOD__ . " is a duplication of " . __FUNCTION__ . " method in CtrlCommonFeatureWeb and CtrlCommonFeatureCms." . PHP_EOL;
   }

   function add() {
      echo __METHOD__ . " is a duplication of " . __FUNCTION__ . " method in CtrlCommonFeatureWeb and CtrlCommonFeatureCms." . PHP_EOL;
   }   

}
```

**CtrlCommonFeatureCms.php**

```
require_once('CtrlBaseCms.php');

class CtrlCommonFeatureCms extends CtrlBaseCms {

   function __construct() {
      echo __METHOD__ . ": " . "This controller functionality (methods index and add) is  common to web, admin and cms." . PHP_EOL;
      parent::__construct();  
   }

   function index() {
      echo __METHOD__ . " is a duplication of " . __FUNCTION__ . " method in CtrlCommonFeatureAdmin and CtrlCommonFeatureWeb." . PHP_EOL;
   }

   function add() {
      echo __METHOD__ . " is a duplication of " . __FUNCTION__ . " method in CtrlCommonFeatureAdmin and CtrlCommonFeatureCms." . PHP_EOL;
   }   

}
```

**CtrlCommonFeatureWeb.php**

```
require_once('CtrlBaseWeb.php');

class CtrlCommonFeatureWeb extends CtrlBaseWeb {

   function __construct() {
      echo __METHOD__ . ": " . "This controller functionality is (methods index and add) common to web, admin and cms." . PHP_EOL;
      parent::__construct();  
   }

   function index() {
      echo __METHOD__ . " is a duplication of " . __FUNCTION__ . " method in CtrlCommonFeatureAdmin and CtrlCommonFeatureCms." . PHP_EOL;
   }

   function add() {
      echo __METHOD__ . " is a duplication of " . __FUNCTION__ . " method in CtrlCommonFeatureAdmin and CtrlCommonFeatureCms." . PHP_EOL;
   }   

}
```

As you can see in this example. the function index and add are the same and when i have to make a change in one of them i have to copy paste it to the others, and these functions obviously they cannot be moved up to the base controller.

Here is a demo code to visualize this:

**usagedemo.php**

```
require_once 'CtrlNotCommon.php';
require_once 'CtrlCommonFeatureWeb.php';
require_once 'CtrlCommonFeatureAdmin.php';

$ctrlNotCommon = new CtrlNotCommon();
$ctrlCommonFeatureWeb = new CtrlCommonFeatureWeb();
$ctrlCommonFeatureWeb->index();
$ctrlCommonFeatureAdmin = new CtrlCommonFeatureAdmin();
$ctrlCommonFeatureAdmin->index();
```

Thank you

Comment: What duplication? Where? It is impossible to understand, what you are even trying to describe. All I get is that you are abusing inheritance a lot.

Comment: @teresko, I modified my question to make it clearer. Let me know if it is still not clear. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason today I cannot format correctly the code inside the question if somebody can help with that, it would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of the code in any of those methods? Just saying that there is duplication is kinda meaningless. And what exactly is the difference between `CtrlBaseAdmin` and `CtrlBaseCMS`?

Comment: Can we please see these 3 CTORs that you are referring to? It may be that you can completely avoid a lvl of inheritance.

Comment: @Abstractioniseverything. I have a problem with my editor. The code for some reason is not compatible with stackoverflow code formating as usual. Once that fixed I will post the code and even a solution that I found using the factory method dp (that maybe is not the best solution).

Comment: Ok, but I think you are on the right track; using a creational DP here. While you are at it, look at Prototype DP as well. Not that it is necessarily more suitable to your particular problem, but I can't tell from what you have given at this point.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to share the code between several stand-alone applications, probably you could create your own library with base controller classes, and use `composer` for dependency management. If there is the same code base, it will be even easier because in that case you can keep base classes right inside the project.
2. You can organise you code using abstract class for base controller and keep shared method there (it their are the same).
3. Another approach is using traits, so you can create the trait, put there all the methods you want to share and then just use that trait in your controllers.

Answer (score -1):

You can:

- Create abstract class User and implements each User controller (UserAdmin/UserCms/UserWeb) ;
- Create core directory of controllers inside core folder where you will use in all your app - Fastest and less coded;

The main idea it's the same: Most of the PHP Frameworks don't rely in heavy OOP and, IMHO, it should. If you are implementing one by yourself, give yourself a chance to do that and save headaches in the future.

Taking the second option it's a ugly way. User can have the same methods at first sight, but the tables which are implemented and some business rules will change when you uses in another system. Doing that way will put a lot of switches and ifs to filter what the current instance is wanting/where it's been called.

The first option would be like that:

```
// Define things a user *has* to be able to do (has to implement)
interface iUser {
    public function set();
    public function get();
    public function setTable();
}

// Define our default abstraction
abstract class DefaultUser implements iUser {
    private $_username = false;
    private $_userid = false;
    protected $_table = false;
    public function get() {
        /* the default implementation */
        echo "defaultUser get";
    }
    public function set() {
        echo "defaultUser set";
    }
}

class UserAdmin extends DefaultUser {
    public function setTable($table) {
        $this->_table = $table;
    }

    public function set() {
        echo "UserAdmin's set() and also my parent's set()";
        parent::set();
    }

    public function get() {
        echo "UserAdmin's get() and also my parent's get()";
        parent::get();
    }
}

class UserCMS extends DefaultUser {
    public function setTable($table) {
        $this->_table = $table;
    }

    public function set() {
        echo "UserCMS's set() and also my parent's set()";
        parent::set();
    }

    public function get() {
        echo "UserCMS's get() and also my parent's get()";
        parent::get();
    }
}
```

PS: Separate classes and interface into different files.

Comment: Whoever down voted this answer, can you please comment. It is unproductive in terms of clarifying what is already a vague question. Assuming your contest is a valid one.

Comment: @Abstractioniseverything. I'm curious too, just waiting to improve my answer, it's complicated down voted without reasons to help with that.